# What is the Graphics object for?

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I'm starting to learn how to program garphics in Java using Java2D.

I have learned that the way to make graphics is by using the paintComponent method. What I don't understand: paintComponent takes a Graphics object as a parameter. What is this object for? Why do I need this in order to draw graphics on a JPanel? (paintComponent is a method inherited from JPanel and overriden in order to create graphics, right)?

Thanks

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but this question could be easily answered by (a) Googling for code examples, or even simpler, (b) reading the Javadocs. Or (c) reading a tutorial.

Comment: I learn only from tutorials, so I did try to find out what this object is for. Couldn't understand.

Comment: It would be better to ask a specific question about a specific line of code in a tutorial that you didn't understand - but try to read the whole code example, or better still the whole tutorial, first.

Comment: All I understand is that we need a JPanel or a PaintComponent to draw on, and this instance has to have a method called paintComponent. In this method we draw the graphics, and then we add the JPanel or PaintComponent to the JFrame. Makes perfect sense.

But why the Graphics object? Why do we need it?

Comment: It's a little off topic, but might help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005505/why-does-one-have-to-use-the-paintcomponent-method-to-draw-in-java/18005806#18005806

Answer (score 1):

The Graphics object is what you actually use to draw into the canvas to render your component.

It's a generic drawing API used in several places throughout Java (for example with Images) to allow you to paint into things.